# Spring Rest Controllers: deployment to Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I want to develop a RESTful API within my multi-module Spring-based project using Spring Rest. For that purpose, I have a webapp module and some other business/data layer modules. For example, this would be my simplified project structure:

```
myProject
  -- webapp (war-packaged)
  -- business (jar-packaged)
  -- data (jar-packaged)
```

Business module depends on data module and so does webapp on business module. Webapp imports successfully every module's application context. Now I want to be able to use some business module classes that do some kind of calculation according to some data retrieved from a DB in order to provide a certain resource. All examples I had a look at were quite simple and this multi-module approach was not covered at all.

What is the problem? As far as I am concerned, Tomcat loads classes in a certain order. Concretely, it first loads WEB-INF/classes and only then WEB-INF/lib (where all webapp dependencies are placed, business module in this case). So, there goes my question. **Where should I place my Controller classes?** If I place them within the webapp module I won't be able to autowire any business-module bean since Tomcat will throw a *ClassNotFoundException* when I deploy the webapp war (at least this is the behaviour I have experienced).

The answer is probably easy but I'm quite new to Spring and its world!

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your business and data jars would go into the WEB-INF/lib directory.  Then those jars will automatically be added to the CLASSPATH for your app when you deploy it.  You will need to deploy your application as a WAR file.

Ideally, you would build the business and data jars, add them to some repository, and then the build system would pull the proper version of each jar into the WEB-INF/lib directory for you.

And as to the original question, the controller classes go into the webapp/src directory.

Comment: I follow your approach @Athrawn17, but if I try to import any class of the business module in a controller class, Tomcat throws the before mentioned error when I deploy the war. Those imports don't show any error in my IDE. I have checked the dependency jar's content and the classes are there, so the only explanation I find is the class loading order in the Tomcat environment as explained, for example, here: http://avricot.com/blog/index.php?post/2011/02/18/tomcat-class-loader%2C-priority-order , where first WEB-INF/classes are first loaded (e.g.: controllers) and only then WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Are you sure that the business module jar is in the WEB-INF/lib directory?  And are you sure the class of the business module that you are referencing is in the business module jar?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Maven 2. Make sure your assembly creator (e.g. maven war module) is including your dependent .jar files within the final .war file's WEB-INF/lib directory.  This should be the default procedure (per: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#dependentWarIncludes ). The other concern, then is whether your sub-projects (business and data) are even creating jars so that they could be included in the WAR output.

If you have doubts as to the contents of that war file, browse the listing of it by executing
'jar tvf $WAR_FILENAME' from the command line and by observing the WEB-INF/lib directory contents.  You should see your business and data jars in there. Go further by exploding your war file, then browsing the contents of business and data jar (using 'jar xvf $FILENAME' to explode in a new directory).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would you have any insight into other build tools, like grable?  Do I need to just add the correct dependencies to my build file?